# Upgrade Business Central from 14.5 to 16.4

Tags: dynamics-business-central

I'm trying to upgrade our Test Environment from Version 14.5 to 16.4 of Business Central following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/upgrade/upgrade-unmodified-application-v14-v16).

Everything was fine until i tried to publish the Base APP

```
Publish-NAVApp -ServerInstance BC160 -Path "<Path>\Applications\BaseApp\Source\Microsoft_Base Application.app"

Publish-NAVApp : Your program license does not allow you to publish 'Upg Load Named Forward Links'. At line:1 char:1
+ Publish-NAVApp -ServerInstance BC160 -Path "...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Publish-NAVApp], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MicrosoftDynamicsNavServer$BC160/nav-systemapplication,Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Apps.Management.Cmdlets.PublishNavApp
```

My License has been updated:

```
Product Line            : Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central on premises Subscription
Product Edition         : Premium
Product Version         : 16
Country                 : Italy
Language                : English (US)
Created Date            : 8/28/2020 5:40:37 AM (-07:00)
****************************************************************************
Name                                                                  Amount
----------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Country Code: W1                                                           1
etc...
```

Somebody have a hint for me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you upload the correct (developer) licence using Import-NAVServerLicence?
If you did, have you restarted the service after?

Comment: No, i tried to do it with my customer license. From the documentation it seemed to me that there is no need of a particular license. So I opened a ticket in Microsoft, they told me that a partner license is needed to do the update.